# I am unable to use match pattern on fast file

Tags: r, fasta

I am trying to find the STOP and START codons in a fasta dataset.

I have tried everything, but the matchpattern (biostring) command is not working and not showing any matches.

```
library(seqinr)
library(Biostrings)
rbcs <- read.fasta(file = "rbcS_sequences_full_edited.fasta", as.string = TRUE, set.attributes = FALSE)
rbcsseq <- rbcs[[1]]
rbcs
atg <- lapply(rbcs, function(x) {
  string <- BString(paste(x, collapse = ""))
  matchPattern("atg", string)
})
```